# Identifying the changes between User and Programmatic in DataGridTextColumn in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I would like to distinguish the change in DataGridTextColumn between progrmmatic and User changes.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Binding="{Binding Position, StringFormat=N2}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
```

In the above column, if user modifies the value of the Position, I need to know to know the value.

I am looking for something similar to [Ignoring text/value changes due to databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841292/ignoring-text-value-changes-due-to-databinding)

Answer (score 1):

So Position is a public property.

Never set Position in your code.  In you code change position (and then NotifyPropertyChanged).  Any call to Position get you know came from the UI.

```
 private sting position;

 public sting Position
 {  
     get { return position; }
     set 
     {
         if (position == value) return;
         position = value;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I had thought about it, but I had to remember which properties to set directly and which properties to set indirectly and it gets cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: Right click Position and select Find All References

Comment: It is hard to maintain code where you have to remember all those places where Setter should not be called directly.

Comment: What is there to remember?  In XAML you bind to Position and in code behind reference position.