# ValueChanged event is happening as a result of Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

On My WPF project, I have a slider control with `Value="{Binding Path=. . .}" ValueChanged=" . . ."`

In this `ValueChanged`'s event handler method , I want to understand whether current event is happening by user which moved the slider or as a result of `Value="{Binding Path=. . .}"`.

How can I understand this?

**Updated: The goal:**

I have a group of checkboxes and by checking any of them, something is added to a *number*. also user can change that *number* with Slider. slider and checkboxes should reflect each other`s changes.

`ValueChanged`'s event handler method is responsible for set checks in checkboxes , and `Value="{Binding Path=. . .}"` is responsible to reflect that *number*'s changes, which initialy comes from checkboxes.

thank you.

Comment: Could you describe a goal? It seems like a bad design, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring text/value changes due to databinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841292/ignoring-text-value-changes-due-to-databinding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question. If you want to know if the Value was changed by the user or by the binding :

RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs.Source will always be the slider. So you will have to do it by yourself.

Let's say you are binding on Value (just add a boolean):

```
    private bool valueChangedByUser = false;
    private double value = 5;
    public double Value
    {
        get 
        { 
            return value; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            valueChangedByUser = true;  
            this.value = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Value"); 
        }
    }
```

And when you change value in your code, just put valueChangedByUser to false.

```
    private void ValueChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (valueChangedByUser)
        {
            /* Value was changed by user */
        }
        else
        {
            /* Value was not changed by user */
        }
    }
```